# how implement pretty urls for tomcat app behind apache proxy

Tags: java, apache, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, mod-proxy

We have a java app that currently uses URLs that contain product IDs - e.g. /product/12345 - and we wish to implement pretty url slugs so that the url can be something like /product/some-product.

We're thinking that we'd want to put Apache in front of tomcat as a proxy.  Does anyone have advice on how apache could somehow lookup the slug in a key-pair database and route the request to tomcat using the format it's expecting?  Or something that achieves the same goal without having to hard-code the routes into an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer and hope that it helps others looking into this issue.

It looks like the [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) directive for mod_rewrite allows the server to perform a lookup in a text file, SQL query, or console app in order to resolve the URL to which it should redirect.